# Align object to Center

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to align the WindowsTerminal.obj.theaterName to center, but I don't want to use an XAML file. If I would change the Text from WindowsTerminal.obj.theaterName to "Cat" it then will display that text in the center.

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                if (WindowsTerminal.obj.theaterName.Length > 0)


                    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock()
                    {

                        Text = WindowsTerminal.obj.theaterName,
                        HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        //TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        Foreground = Brushes.AliceBlue,
                        Margin = new Thickness(2)
                    };
                    sp.Children.Add(txt);


                }
```

Comment: The code is fine. If you don't see it in the center try coloring the stack panel and its parents separately, to see which one isn't stretching long enough

Comment: Thank you I didn't think of that